# C#. Ограничения использования класса, базовый класс которого объявлен в сборке, на которую нет ссылки

Tags: c#, .net, классы

Пример. C#, 3.5
Есть сборка BaseDLL в которой объявлен класс BaseClass.
Есть сборка CoreDll в которой объявлен интерфейс ICoreClass и класс CoreClass : BaseClass, ICoreClass. Сборка имеет ссылку на BaseDll.
Есть сборка Project, которая использует ссылку только на CoreDLL.

В сборке Project
Можно:
CoreClass cs = new CoreClass();
CoreClass.Поле = значение.

Нельзя (требуется добавить ссылку на сборку BaseDLL):
ICoreClass Ics = new CoreClass();
cs.Метод();

Все public. Компилятор указывает отсутствие ссылки на сборку BaseDLL.

Интересует вопрос почему в ряде случаев требуется ссылка на сборку BaseDLL, а в других случаях не требуется. На вскидку, используется только функционал из сборки CoreDLL. Базовый класс не имеет методов или полей. При этом почему можно присваивать значения полям, но нельзя использовать методы.
При этом можно присвоить экземпляр CoreClass интерфейсу Ics через ref в конструкторе CoreClass, если создать подобный конструктор.

Comment: За это отвечают модификаторы доступа к классам и их членам `public`, `internal`, `private`, `protected`. Больше никаких ограничений на сборки-пересборки нет. А так, уровень абстракции вопроса зашкаливает. Конкретизируйте. Что такое 3.5 я не понял, фреймворк 15-летней давности?

Comment: Он самый. В более свежих версиях вы получите тот же результат.
Все public. Если бы дело было в этом, компилятор указал бы на модификаторы доступа как на источник ошибки. 
Я могу привести код, он не сильно будет отличаться от описания.
Как я уже написал, все проблемы можно обойти с помощью различных способов. Интересно именно почему подобный эффект возникает.
Например, если в базовом классе есть поле, ему нельзя будет присвоить значение. Тут все очевидно. Но его можно переопределить. А почему не работает присвоение самого экземпляра или методы, которых вообще нет в базовом классе - неясно.

Comment: А проблема то в чем? Ссылку на сборку никак не добавить? Вообще в старых дотнетах с этими ссылками много проблем было, поэтому в .NET Core и новее, сборки подключаются как зависимые проекты и если дочерняя сборка ссылкается на еще что-то, то это что-то будет автоматом подхвачено в освновной проект. То есть указанной вами проблемы потенциально нет, хотя я сам в такие дебри не залезал и с проблемой не сталкивался.

Comment: Да проблемы как таковой нет) Например, в .NET 6.0 подобных ошибок не возникает. 
Просто интересно, почему такое вообще может происходить.

Comment: Потому что .NET 6 использует новую систему подключения зависимых сборок, которая в частности исправляет указанную вами проблему.

Comment: Значит это баг, а не фича. В любом случае благодарю за участие в обсуждении вопроса)